# Filling Polygon in basemap with get_axis_bgcolor function was deprecated in version 2.0

Tags: python, polygon, shapefile, matplotlib-basemap

I'm trying to do color filling the polygon in Basemap. But I always got the error `get_axis_bgcolor function was deprecated in version 2.0` and the color would not show up. I used `pip install basemap` and `conda install -c conda-forge basemap` to reinstall the `basemap` as stated in [here in python3.6](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/7808/). The shapefile [can be found here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=15azTDz7quw110RhSpuG7LJwYpyhAo_ij). And the original shapefiles [are provided here](http://www.nyc.gov/html/tlc/html/about/trip_record_data.shtml).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon
import shapefile
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

m = Basemap(projection = 'mill', llcrnrlat=40.47,urcrnrlat=40.95,\
        llcrnrlon=-74.28,urcrnrlon=-73.70,resolution='f') # mill = Miller cylindrical cordinates, resolution c or f
m.drawcoastlines()
# m.drawcounties()
m.drawrivers()
m.fillcontinents(color='w', lake_color = 'lightslategrey')
m.drawmapboundary()
m.readshapefile('~/Desktop/Capstone2017/taxi_zones/taxi_zones_WGS84','taxi_zones_WGS84')

sf=shapefile.Reader('~/Desktop/Capstone2017/taxi_zones/taxi_zones_WGS84')

shape_ex = sf.shape(13)
x_lon = np.zeros((len(shape_ex.points)))
y_lat = np.zeros((len(shape_ex.points)))
for ip in range(len(shape_ex.points)):
    x_lon[ip] = shape_ex.points[ip][0]
    y_lat[ip] = shape_ex.points[ip][1]

region = np.dstack((x_lon, y_lat))[0]
poly = Polygon(region, facecolor='r', edgecolor='k')
ax.add_patch(poly)
```

The full traceback of the error message:

```
/Users/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/basemap/__init__.py:1707: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: The get_axis_bgcolor function was deprecated in version 2.0. Use get_facecolor instead.
  if self.projection not in ['geos','ortho','nsper']:
/Users/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/basemap/__init__.py:1563: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: The get_axis_bgcolor function was deprecated in version 2.0. Use get_facecolor instead.
  x = len(yy)*[self.xmin]; y = yy.tolist()
```

My result looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Why do you read the shapefile twice? Could you make your shapefile available somehow, so that your code is runnable?

Comment: The first read was to plot the all the shapes on map and second call was trying to color filing one of them.  Is there a better way to approach it?